# for() loop after fork stops child creation

Tags: c, for-loop, fork

I am having a problem with fork on my system
with this program:

```
# include <assert.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        fork();
        printf("getpid():%i",getpid());
        for( i=0; i<10;i++)
        {   
            printf("%i\t",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like it to fork for several times and to make the second for loop in each fork child. But the first "for" loop seems to block at the first fork process.

I get only this output:

```
getpid():45200  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9getpid():45210 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Instead of all the other output that should normally be printed by the childrens if they executed the second "for" loop properly.

Comment: End all your printfs with newlines or call `fflush(stdout)`, so the output buffer is flushed.

Comment: Note that you're going to get more than 5 processes, because the child processes continue the outer loop and fork their own children. You'll get 15 total processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is working fine. Use different variables in the 2 loops for iterations. Also, slightly edited print statements for readability.

```
# include <assert.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        fork();
        printf("getpid():%i ",getpid());
        for(int j=0; j<10;j++) //Use variable j instead of i.
        {
            printf("%i\t",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```